# What force opposes acceleration in a frictionless vacuum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Accelerating a huge rocket in space requires far more force than accelerating a tiny object to the same speed, proportional to the difference in their masses.  But...what is the "force" that is resisting the acceleration so much more in the large object? Of course, it's the larger mass, but that doesn't answer the question...mass isn't a force. Trying to make sense of the mysterious underlying rule of nature that appears to effect this.

Comment: Why do you think there needs to be a "force" "resisting" the acceleration? The tendency of objects to "resist acceleration" is called [inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia) and is not a force.

Comment: ACurious...because of there wasn't, a slight tap on rocket with a finger should send it hurtling at close to the speed of light. Something must be preventing that, and it isn't static friction...

Answer (score 1):

You need a force to cause acceleration. But the amount of acceleration is resisted by what is called **inertia**.

**Mass** is linear inertia.

You seem to have an idea that alterations in acceleration must require force. And yes, force is one of the things needed. But other things can alter acceleration as well. Both force and inertia can do that.

Always think of Newton's second law as a whole. This is where force and acceleration are tied together. But they are not alone - mass is a player as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no force resisting acceleration. Instead there is only a force being created by the thrust of the rocket. If two identical rocket engines are used, one on a very massive payload, and one on a much less massive payload, then in order to achive equal acceleration, the more massive payload will require more force due to the F=ma relationship.

Comment: I understand that, all you really did was rephrase my question into an equation...I'm asking, specificallly, why mass appears at all in the equation, considering there is no gravity acting upon the object in space, it is not clear to me why in fact Mass matters.  Obviously it does, but I'm trying to understand why,

Comment: This is  much more interesting question, ie you are asking "Why does inertia exist ?" For undergraduates it is simply presented as being a fundamental property of nature, without any real explanation of why. For graduates, inertia is believed to be either related to the higgs boson and its interactions, or a consequence of string theory (albeit requiring 11 dimensions to express), or possibly even derivable from Maxwells equations of electromagnetic fields (but this is a controversial proposal). In other words, we dont really for sure how inertia happens, but we do have a couple of hypotheses.

Answer (score -2):

Force is balanced by the time derivative (aka change) of momentum.